# input_alternative error on export_savedmodel in Tensorflow

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow

I have a simple LinearModel with two sparse and two real-valued features. I trained it and now I want to export it with the export_savedmodel. Referencing few sources I came up with something along the lines of:

```
feature_spec = create_feature_spec_for_parsing(
    [
        real_valued_column_1, real_valued_column_2,
        sparse_column_1, sparce_column_2
    ]
)
input_receiver_fn = tf.estimator.export.build_parsing_serving_input_receiver_fn(feature_spec)
my_estimator.export_savedmodel('my_model/', serving_input_fn=input_receiver_fn)
```

where:

```
real_valued_column_1 = tf.contrib.layers.real_valued_column(
    'avg_consumption_h')
sparse_column_1 = tf.contrib.layers.sparse_column_with_integerized_feature("sparse_1", bucket_size=24)
```

Unfortunately I get `ValueError: A default input_alternative must be provided.` on `export_savedmodel`. I digged in a little into the codebase of tensorflow and it seems that `build_parsing_serving_input_receiver_fn` always returns `ServingInputReceiver` but the method that extracts input_alternatives always creates them empty if `serving_input_fn` passed to export_savedmodel is not of the type `InputFnOps`.

Is `build_parsing_serving_input_receiver_fn` somehow deprecated, something is wrong in the process of extraction of input_alternative, or maybe I'm misunderstanding process completely and doing something wrong?

I'm using python 3.6 with tensorflow 1.2, my model is a simple `tf.contrib.learn.LinearRegressor`.

Comment: [Example of export_savedmodel function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48329456/4268517)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try the following

```
from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn.utils.input_fn_utils import build_parsing_serving_input_fn
input_receiver_fn = build_parsing_serving_input_fn(feature_spec)
```

Comment: Thanks, it works! [The current docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/saved_model#using_savedmodel_with_estimators) though still point to the version that cl0udburst used, could you give more hints what does it do and why it's different?